# Android Studio: Getting id of Dialog TextView in another class?

Tags: java, android, dialog

I'm trying to create a couple of Progress Bars inside a Dialog "remaining_amount_report" in Activtiy A:

```
public void setProgressBars(){
    ProgressBar_Setup setup = new ProgressBar_Setup();
    setup.createProgressBar(1, "product1", 80);
    setup.createProgressBar(2, "product2", 60);
    setup.createProgressBar(3, "product3", 100);
    setup.createProgressBar(4, "product4", 20);

}
```

Therefore I've created a Class "ProgressBar_Setup" where the Method is reachable.
But the problem is, since I want to overwrite some TextView Texts of the Dialog, I need to get access to the Dialog inside the Class.

The Class extends Activity A, so I normally should get access just like this:

```
public void createProgressBar(int position, String productname, int progress) {

    mposition = position;
    switch(mposition){
        case 1:
            progressbar[0].setProductname(((TextView) remaining_amount_report.findViewById(R.id.remaining_amount_productname_1)));
```

But I get an Null Object Reference Error, by doing this.

Then I tried a different way, by adding a Dialog Variable to the "createProgressBar"-Method (not really good behavour, I guess):

```
 public void setProgressBars(){
    ProgressBar_Setup setup = new ProgressBar_Setup();
    setup.createProgressBar(1, "product1", 80, remaining_amount_report);
    setup.createProgressBar(2, "product2", 60, remaining_amount_report);
    setup.createProgressBar(3, "product3", 100, remaining_amount_report);
    setup.createProgressBar(4, "product4", 20, remaining_amount_report);
```

And in the ProgressBar_Setup-Class

```
public void createProgressBar(int position, String productname, int progress, Dialog dialog) {

    mposition = position;
    switch(mposition){
        case 1:
            progressbar[0].setProductname(((TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.remaining_amount_productname_1)));
```

But still the same error.

Could you help me here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `findViewById` to first link the views in `progressbar`.

Comment: Could you give me an Example? Don't know exactly what you mean.. I'm sorry.

Comment: First, its always better to upload the entire class files rather than single functions for more context, only then i can see how variables are being referenced. Thank you!